# How can I automate the process of code review

Tags: php, python, .net, code-reviews

I have a team that works on multiple technologies. I want to know how can I automate the process of code review for .Net, .Net MVC, Python, PHP, Drupal and HTML5/CSS with JavaScript.

I have read about and have used some tools like StyleCop/FxCop for .Net and PHP Code Sniffer and likes for PHP and pyLint for Python.

I understand that automated code reviews do not fully replace the manual ones, but I want to setup a process to support manual code reviews.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well you can rely on some best ***Code Analysis Tools*** specific to your language. This tools will be like plugins to your IDEs. you will get code review comments to some decent extent while you code.You can also manually run the tool. I don't have any idea on PHP but we use PMD, check styles for the same purpose in java development.

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In projects where it's available it can be a good idea to implement unit testing. On smaller builds you could set it up (in Visual Studio at least) to have your tests run on build and compile (on large projects with large tests this will increase your compile time by *a lot* though...)